# App.Config Ignored After Pre-Build Event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, app-config

I have a solution with several projects and several developers, each with their own environment (of course).  To manage connection strings between each environment, I have created several app.config files for each environment: app.config.dev, app.config.qa, etc.

The pre-build event simply copies the app.config.$(ConfigurationName) to app.config.  This pre-build event is done for each project in the solution, and the connection string is included in each (including the test project).

When I use the pre-build events to manage the app.config files, the connection string cannot be found.  I can get the tests to run fine by 2 methods: 1. Do not use the pre-build events to manage the app.config file selection, and do it myself or 2. If I check out app.config and make it writable, then the pre-build events work just fine.

We are using Visual Studio 2008 with VSS.

I'm down to my last grey hair here, any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**
Update the pre-build event to ensure the app.config file is writable even if it is checked in.  Pre-Build event used below:
`@echo off`

`attrib -r $(ProjectDir)app.config`
`if errorlevel 1 goto AttribFailed`

`copy $(ProjectDir)app.config.$(ConfigurationName) $(ProjectDir)app.config`
`goto BuildOK`

`:AttribFailed`
`echo Attrib -r Failed on $(ProjectDir)app.config`
`exit 1`

`:BuildOK`
`echo Copy Done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your app.config shouldn't be under source control - just the build-configuration-specific configuration files (app.config.dev, app.config.qa, etc.).

Having said that, you can make checked-in files writable under VSS. For example, through windows explorer, uncheck the file's "Read-only" attribute. (You'll have to do this each time you check it in.)

Comment: If app.config is not in the solution and not under source control, then it is not used when building the application and I do not have access to the config string.  I will try making it writable prior to the build events without checking the file out.

Comment: Updated the Pre-Build event to make the file writable did the trick.  Thank you @HansPassant for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the .config files checked-in has one side-effect, the files stay read-only.  Which has one side-effect, you cannot copy a file over a read-only file and you can't delete it.  Which goes a long way towards explaining why you can't make it work.

Comment: Better to make the copy writable with attrib.exe +r in the post build event.

Comment: I had tried that already, but I messed up the syntax for attrib.  Adding the error handling code helped identify the problem.