# overriding App.Config in prebuild and Use Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, app-config, application-settings, pre-build-event

I have a Settings files that is attached to app.config and I'm using pre-Build command line to call a bat file that supposes to override app.config based on the selected configuration for the project (Debug, release ...) before the build process. everything looks good, app.config is get updated on the build time (I can see the changes in settings and app.config). But when I'm trying to get any value in the settings using some command like this:

```
var test = Settings.Default.DBConn;
```

BUT... for the first time (that app.config is not get override) everything works fine, but when I'm changing the configuration (let's say from debug to release) an error is throwing that says something is wrong with the xml or something like that, the error is ConfigurationErrorsException, and the message is

> The value of the property 'serializeAs' cannot be parsed. The error
>   is: The enumeration value must be one of the following: String, Xml,
>   Binary, ProviderSpecific.

Here is my bat file:

```
@echo off


if %1==Debug  GOTO DE
if %1==DEV GOTO DEV
if %1==Release GOTO PR



:DE
xcopy  %2configs\app_Debug.config  %2app.config  /Y
GOTO END

:PR
xcopy  %2configs\app_PROD.config  %2app.config  /Y
GOTO END

:DEV
xcopy  %2configs\app_DEV.config  %2app.config /Y
GOTO END

:END
```

I really don't know what is the problem I checked out these discussions

[hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx)

[Overriding App.Config settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305279/overriding-app-config-settings)

[Manage multiple app config files during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319524/app-config-ignored-after-pre-build-event)

and few more. But I couldn't find any solution. 
Could you please help me on this! 
Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://mitasoft.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/multipleappconfig/

Comment: @Crono, Thanks link was interesting, but doesn't help! :(

Comment: There's something wrong with the .bat file, I suppose.  Nobody can see it, we can't even see the changed .config file.  No point in keeping that a secret, you must document your question properly.

Comment: Config files are exactly the same as the main app.config file just few values are changed.

Comment: When you run this pre-build does it break for all three variations(DE, PR, and DEV)?

Comment: Yes, basically every time that I'm overriding the app.config the error  is happen, if I removed XCOPY command on DE label, means that there is  no override anymore, it is working without any problem. so Something is happening when app.config is get override.

Comment: Could you switch to use config transforms instead of overwriting, using Slow Cheetah? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: Are you sure the batch file is being called for each environment?  I would have it write a small blank text file each time it's run, then run it with each config to ensure that it's being run.  Or just add an echo at the end for "Operation Successful" and ensure it shows up in the build output for each config.  If that's working, then we'd need to see some more context to help properly, I think.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Visual Studio extension called SloWCheetah which is designed for this purpose. It allows you to provided XSLT transforms to the app.config for each of your build configurations. Check it out http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: If you want to have the same result by doing it manually [you can do that.](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.fr/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html)  It's quick and elegant :)